# Integrate Application between ClickOnce deployment and standalone package

Tags: clickonce

I'm facing a very big problem right now.
I want to support 2 installation mechanism for my application.

1. Build a setup file. I can install in local machine.
   This application just works in local mode.
2. Publish the setup using ClickOnce.

Only one of them should be allowed to exist on a single machine

This means:

- If I have already installed the ClickOnce version, I must not be allowed
   to install the standalone version. (In this case a message box should be displayed)
- If I have installed the standalone package, the ClickOnce setup should ask me if I want to upgrade the standalone version to the ClickOnce version, removing the standalone version in the process.

I've been thinking about this for many nights, but I cannot think of a way to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The following information may help you

1. Creating a custom ClickOnce installer: http://tinyurl.com/custominstaller
2. Creating a customer ClickOnce installer (MSDN): http://tinyurl.com/custominstallermsdn
3. Administering ClickOnce deployments: http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/aa480721.aspx

The options explained in those articles should give you enough information to build a custom
installer that will check for the standalone installation on the system and take appropriate action.

However... normally ClickOnce applications do not require administrative privileges to be installed while normal applications do. This means that if the ClickOnce installer is run as a normal user, it may not have enough privileges to check which applications are installed on the computer.

Both the standalone and ClickOnce application do have access to the roaming profile diretories
of the user so you may be able to store some information there. ('Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData')

Your custom ClickOnce installer can check that directory to find an indication that the standalone applicatin was installed and your standalone installer could do the same.

In fact your standalone installer could be the clickonce installer at the same time.
You build a custom installer that can install either version... giving the user the option.

Bottom line: build a customer installer